# How to execute the code of VB 6 from Visual Studio 2010, or I need to download VB 6?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vb6

Can anyone guide me ,whether is aany method to open a VB6 code from Visual Studio 2010?
Or i need to download VB 6 Compiler separately?(If yes, then please send the link from where i can download the VB6 or guide me from where i can download it?)

Comment: are you talking about opening the code files to view them or executing and debugging the code?

Comment: what's your goal: to read the code, or to compile the code and perform maintenance/enhancements?

Comment: need only to view the code and compile it, donot edit the code!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Visual Studio (starting with Visual Studio .NET 2002) does not compile Visual Basic 6.0 projects. You will need to legally obtain Visual Basic 6.0 to compile the code.

If you just need the Visual Basic 6.0 runtime, most modern Windows versions have it installed.

Comment: From where i can download the VB 6, as i donot want to purchase it, as its just a week work!

Comment: @Asad - If you've got an MSDN subscription you can download it from there.

Comment: Yes I have MSDN subscribtion, so will now download it from there. Thankyou very much for all experts comments!!!

Answer (score 1):

No you can't, you'll need a copy of Visual Basic 6.  You can get it from MSDN.